# extract partial attributes of an object using typescript types

Tags: typescript, spread-syntax

how to extract partial attributes of an object using typescript types? is it even possible?

```
export interface Product {
  brandName: string;
  modelNo: string;
  rate: number | null;
  someOtherProp1: string;
  someOtherProp2: string;

}


export interface OrderItem {
  modelNo: string;
  rate: number;
  qty: number;
}

const exampleProduct: Product = {
  brandName: "Example Brand",
  modelNo: "12345",
  rate: 100,
  someOtherProp1: "Some Value 1",
  someOtherProp2: "Some Value 2"
};
```

Then how can i create an instance of order item from product, i tried following which does not work:

```
const exampleOrderItem: OrderItem = {
  ...exampleProduct,
  qty: 10
};
```

Comment: TypeScript types don't exist at runtime so there's no way to do this automatically with pure TypeScript. You have to explicitly mention the keys you want to keep or exclude. See the linked q/a for more information.